# Spring Boot + Activiti

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activiti, spring-initializr

I want to start a new Spring Boot + Activiti project using the Spring Initializr, but the Activiti dependency does not show up on the dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this dependency to you pom :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
   <version>${activiti.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Ref : https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/08/getting-started-with-activiti-and-spring-boot